# consuming concurrently a collection using reactor

Tags: java, project-reactor

from time to time have to implement the classic concurrent producer-consumer solution  across the project I'm involved in, pretty much the problem is reduced in having some  collection which gets populated from multiple threads and which is being consumed by several consumers. 
In a nutshell the collection say is bounded to 10k entities, 
once buffer size is hit a worker task is submitted consuming these 10k entities, there is a limit of such workers say its set to 10, which in worst case scenario means I can have up to 10 workers each consuming 10k entities.

I do have to play with some locking here and there some checks around buffer overflows (case when producers generate too much data while all workers are busy processing their chunks) thus have to discard new events to avoid OOM (not the best solution but stability is p1 ;))

Was looking these days around reactor and a way to use it instead of going low level and do all the things described above, so the dumb question is: "can reactor be used for this use case?"
for now forget about overflow/discarding.. how can i achieve the N consumers for a broadcaster?

was looking particularly around broadcaster with the buffer + a thread pooled dispatcher:

```
void test() {
  final Broadcaster<String> sink =   Broadcaster.create(Environment.initialize());
  Dispatcher dispatcher = Environment.newDispatcher(2048, 20, DispatcherType.WORK_QUEUE);

  sink
    .buffer(100)
    .consumeOn(dispatcher, this::log);

  for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    sink.onNext("elementent " + i);
    if (i%1000 == 0) {
      System.out.println("addded elements " + i);
    }
  }
}
 void log(List<String> values) {
  System.out.print("simulating slow processing....");
  System.out.println("processing: " + Arrays.toString(values.toArray()));
  try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

my intention here is have a broadcaster execute the log(..) in asynch manner when buffer size was reached, however it looks like it is always executing log(...) it in blocking mode. executing 100 once done next 100 and so on.. how can i make it asynch ?

thanks
vyvalyty

Answer (score 0):

A possible pattern is to use flatMap with publishOn:

```
Flux.range(1, 1_000_000)
.buffer(100)
.flatMap(b -> Flux.just(b).publishOn(SchedulerGroup.io())
   .doOnNext(this::log))
.consume(...);
```